# CGAL linker error - Symbol not found: ___gmpq_clear

Tags: swig, cgal

I'm trying to incorporate CGAL into an existing simulation project, but am having some linker trouble.  The python simulation keiro.py uses a file called physics.cpp in a swig wrapper for speeding up common operations...I managed to get my physics.cpp file to compile, but running the Python simulation errors out with the following message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "keiro.py", line 2, in 
>      from world import World, View
>    File "/Users/marcstrauss/Desktop/keiro/world.py", line 9, in 
>      from fast.physics import Vec2d, Particle, World as PhysicsWorld
>    File "/Users/marcstrauss/Desktop/keiro/fast/physics.py", line 7, in 
>      import _physics
>   ImportError: dlopen(/Users/marcstrauss/Desktop/keiro/fast/*physics.so, 2): Symbol not >found: _*_gmpq_clear
>    Referenced from: /Users/marcstrauss/Desktop/keiro/fast/_physics.so
>    Expected in: flat namespace
>   in /Users/marcstrauss/Desktop/keiro/fast/_physics.so

I figure that error with the ___gmpq_clear symbol not being recognized in the object file means that I'm not linking to CGAL properly.  Here is my makefile:

> all: physics.py _physics.so graphutils.py _graphutils.so
>
> _physics.so: setup_physics.py physics_wrap.cxx physics.cpp
>   python setup_physics.py build_ext --inplace  -I/opt/local/include/
>
> _graphutils.so: setup_graphutils.py graphutils_wrap.cxx graphutils.cpp
>   python setup_graphutils.py build_ext --inplace -I/opt/local/include/
>
> physics.py physics_wrap.cxx: physics.i physics.h
>   swig -python -c++ physics.i
>
> graphutils.py graphutils_wrap.cxx: graphutils.i graphutils.h
>   swig -python -c++ graphutils.i -I/opt/local/include/
>   clean:
>   rm -f physics.py
>   rm -f graphutils.py
>   rm -f *.cxx
>   rm -f *~ *.pyc *.pyo
>   rm -f *.so
>   rm -rf build

Does anyone have any ideas for me as to how to fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: Did the answer fix your problem?  I've having similar issues at the moment?

Comment: Yes, it did. At least for me. I'm using Xcode 4 under Mac OS X Lion. I installed CGAL using MacPorts.

Answer (score 7):

On my computer the `__gmpq_clear` symbol is located in the libgmp library:

```
nm libgmp.a | grep gmpq_clear
00000000 T __gmpq_clear
```

Try adding `-lgmp` to your linking command.